# Is this statement true $\text { Let } x_{0} \in \mathbb{R} . \text { Then } \lim _{x \rightarrow x_{0}} f(x)=0$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function $
f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}{0} & {x=0 \vee x \notin \mathbb{Q}} \\ {\frac{1}{q}} & {x=\frac{p}{q} \operatorname{with} p, q \neq 0 \text { and } p, q \text { relativ prime}}\end{array}\right.$

Now assume the statement: $\text { Let } x_{0} \in \mathbb{R} . \text { Then } \lim _{x \rightarrow x_{0}} f(x)=0$.

According to the official solution of the exercise sheet this statement is true. But i don't understand why. For example $5 \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f(5) = 1$ because $\frac{5}{1} = 5$ so $q = 1 $ and $\frac{1}{q} = 1$. Which is a contradiction to $\lim _{x \rightarrow x_{0}} f(x)=0$.

Is the solution wrong or am I making a mistake )

Comment: Your computation at $x=5$ is not a contradiction. It only shows that if the limit is zero, which it is, then it is not equal to the value at the point. Those values are equal when the function is continuous at $x=5$. This function is not continuous at $x=5$.

Comment: This is a clear example of a "beautiful" non continous function.

Comment: When we are talking about limit of a function then we are NOT talking about its value at a specific point. Thus the assumed statement has nothing to do with $f(5)=1$. Also try to prove the assumed statement.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\epsilon>0$ and choose $N$ such that $\frac{1}{N}<\epsilon$. For simplicity, start by choosing $\delta_0=1$. Notice that the set $A=\{\frac{p}{q}\in N_{\delta_0}(x_0)\cap \mathbb{Q}: |q|\leq N\}$ consists of a finite number of isolated points. Hence, choose $\delta_1=dist(x_0,A\backslash\{x_0\})$ and then $\delta=\min\{\delta_0,\delta_1\}$. Then for all $x\in N_\delta(x_0)$, either $x$ is irrational and $f(x)=0<\epsilon$ or $x$ is rational and $f(x)=\frac{1}{q}$ with $|q|>N$. But then $|f(x)|<\frac{1}{N}<\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

You're making a mistake.  The function isn't continuous at $5$, and hence we don't have $\lim_{x\to 5}f(x)=f(5)$.